# JavaFX interfacing with C++

Tags: java, c++11, javafx, java-native-interface

I have a JavaFX GUI Calculator built and I have a C++ shared library declaring all the functions , such as addition , multiplication etc.
What I would like to do is , call the c++ functions on button click on the calculator App. How would I do that ?

Comment: Some [alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3422673/230513).

Comment: To call C++ from Java, you need to write a JNI interface for the C++ code. The JNI spec can be found on the Oracle web site. If you Google "JNI tutorial" you'll find a ton of information. It's pretty easy.